# How do I implement Google Adwords tracking on a Force.com Site?

Tags: force.com-sites, google

I have a Newsletter signup form exposed through a Force.com site on a wordpress site. I was just looking to implement Google adwords tracking when someone signsup.

And I found this through a blog -

```
<apex:page controller="WebLeadController" sidebar="false" showHeader="false" cache="false"> <apex:define name="body"> 
<apex:form> 
<apex:pageBlock mode="edit"> 
<apex:pageBlockSection > 
<input type="hidden" name="sfga" value="00D30000000WnPC"/> 
<apex:inputField value="{!Lead.LastName}"/> 
<apex:inputField value="{!Lead.Email}"/> 
</apex:pageBlockSection> 
<apex:pageBlockSection > 
<apex:commandButton value="Create this lead" action="{!save}"/> </apex:pageBlockSection> 
</apex:pageBlock> 
</apex:form>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://lct.salesforce.com/sfga.js"></script> <script type="text/javascript">__sfga();</script> </apex:define> </apex:page>
```

I am just curious where do I put the Conversion ID URL (Conversion ID - 12345689)?

```
<noscript>
<div style="display:inline;">
<img height="1" width="1" style="border-style:none;" alt="" src="//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion/123456789/?label=AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA&amp;guid=ON&amp;script=0"/>
</div>
</noscript>
```

Answer (score 1):

As per Google AdWords, the code needs to be inserted between the `<body>` tags. Thus, you just need to put the Adwords code anywhere between the `<apex:page>` tag and it should work.

Comment: Is it the same way I've mentioned above (the first block) and replacing the Org ID? What would this track? Will it track the number of hits on the page or the number of submits? Do you have any Example that you can point me to?